# How can I focus a TextInput after it has loaded in an efficient way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to be able to focus the TextInput after it has mounted and I've had a couple of solutions for this but sadly none of them works

My TextInput is multiline and I'm setting the selection too to bring the cursor at the end of text

- autoFocus prop: causes navigation issues
- using ref to focus

```
<ScreenWrapper
 onEntryTransitionEnd={() => {
   inputRef.focus();
   input.setSelectionRange(input.value.length, input.value.length);
 }}
 >
  <TextInput
    ref={(el) => inputRef.current = el}
  >
```

This doesn't focus the TextInput if I reload the page. I believe by the time focus is called, TextInput hasn't mounted

- ref plus useEffect

Basically the same as above but I added a hook to run on change in ref.current

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(inputRef.current) inputRef.current.focus();
}, [inputRef.current])
```

This worked perfectly but react recommends against the use of refs as dependents

How can I achieve this efficiently?

I also tried setting a state when I set the ref value in TextInput. And then using an effect hook on that state, but it shows similar results as autoFocus, causing navigation transition issues

Navigation issue example can be seen here, https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/236

I'm experiencing the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

Can you call focus on it as soon as it loads by using a [callback ref](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback)

e.g.

```
<ScreenWrapper>
  <TextInput
    ref={useCallback((el) => {
       if(el) el.focus()
    },[])}
  />
...
```

Comment: This causes the same rightward animation effect like autoFocus

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/236

This is what I mean by navigation issue @adam-jenkins